# How to compile Fetch API and promises for browser compatibility?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm curious as to what the best solutions are when you want to use fetch() and promises and have it compiled/poly-filled for optimal browser support.

When I try to compile fetch/promise code on babeljs.io I do not see a compiled version, so this is leaving me a bit confused as to how I can use fetch and promises instead of XML and have good browser support?

The result I get from the babel compiler. It is not what I was expecting apart from changing const to var:

```
const image = document.querySelector('.my-image');
fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
}).then(function(blob) {
  const objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  image.src = objectURL;
});
```

vs

```
var image = document.querySelector('.my-image');
fetch('flowers.jpg').then(function(response) {
  return response.blob();
}).then(function(blob) {
  var objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  image.src = objectURL;
});
```

Comment: You need to configure Babel to tell it what your target environment is. See https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration.

Comment: Separately: I don't think Babel itself provides a `fetch` polyfill. There are many available though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Hey...i appreciate the help. So you mean even with configuration Babel cannot polyfill fetch? And if it doesn't what other tools do you suggest i can use to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Babel deals with syntax translation (`const` to `var`, as you have seen, is one simple example).  To deal with fetch or promises, if not supported, then you need to include suitable libraries - how to do this depends on your target environment, but if in the browser you could use webpack, or just include them with script tags.

Comment: @EuanSmith ....Thanks a ton.....I had a rough idea that this might be possible with webpack as im just starting to get my head around webpack. My environment is the browser yes! So webpack can achieve this?

Comment: Yes.  Webpack can be used to bundle together the assets you need, libraries, css, images, and polyfills.  There are other ways of doing it (script tags), so you need to decide what is right for you, but all can work.  Webpack is a powerful tool and can do a lot, so going through some tutorials is _strongly_ reccommended.

Comment: For a polyfill I found this: https://github.com/github/fetch, you can install it from npm and bundle using webpack, or you can download a js file to include in a script tag. Of course other polyfills are available, this was just a 1 minute search.

Comment: @EuanSmith - Babel makes a lot of polyfills available via [`@babel/polyfill`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#docsNav), but I think it's just JS features (`Promise`, etc.), not web platform features like `fetch`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  yes, that's my understanding too.  Even if it did include `fetch` I would argue against just including the full bundle, not all will be needed.  As a more philosophical point it always makes me sad to see code transpiled and polyfilled down to the lowest common denominator (nothing against babel of course).  I can't wait for IE to finally go away so we can all stop doing so much of this.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the advice, it's really helped. Just a last question...., The polyfill that you mentioned is great but i forgot to mention that i would also need for this to work in node.js environments as well as the browser, does webpack's solution deal with both the browser and node.js environments?

Comment: @EuanSmith - Well, hopefully people are serving modern content with `type="module"` and this ES5 stuff with `nomodule`. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, i managed to find the right solution i was looking for, if either of you want to submit the answer i will gladly resolve it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Babel deals (primarily) with syntax translation, such as converting `const` (and `let`) to suitable `var` declarations.  While it does provide polyfills through [`@babel/polyfill`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill#docsNav), `fetch` is not one of those provided.

There are many fetch polyfills, one example, assuming your project is browser-based, is [here](https://github.com/github/fetch).  To include it in your project you can either download the `.umd.js` package and include it in a `<script>` tag, or use a bundler such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) to build it into your project.